# Call the name of a Texbox with number changing in Visual Basic 6

Tags: textbox, vb6

I'm use Visual Basic 6 to create a table with many Textbox which named txtNo1, txtNo2, txtNo3,...
I want to use the "For...Next..." loop to assign a content to these Textbox.
How can I call all these Textbox in the simplest way?

```
For i = 1 to 100
    txtNo (......) .txt = "ABC"
Next i
```

Comment: Use `For Each...Next` to loop over the `Controls` collection instead

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_array

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using unique textboxes, each with a unique name, you should use a (textbox) control array:

- Place the 1st textbox on the form, name it 'txtNo'
- Copy it and paste it onto the form
- VB will ask you "There's already a control named 'txtNo'. Would you like to create a control array?". Answer "Yes"
- Paste as the textbox as many times as you need it

Then your code looks like

```
' Control arrays typically start at index 0
For i = 0 to 100
    txtNo(i) .txt = "ABC"
Next i
```

Jim Mack's solution works as well, code for it:

```
' Assuming your form is named 'Form1'
For each ctrl in Form1.Controls
   If TypeOf ctrl Is Textbox
      For i = 1 To 100
         If ctrl.Name = "txtNo" & CStr(i) Then
            ctrl.Text = "ABC"
         End If
      End If
   End If
```

It's a bit more complex, but therefore more flexible as works with multiple control types (in one loop).

Comment: Very good answer, because VB6 has a limit of how many controls you can have on form, and a control array counts as 1 instead of - in the case of the op - 100.

Comment: A wonderful help! I met that question every time copy and paste an element, but now I understand!

Comment: Consider marking my answer as "accepted" _(I think that's what it called)_ then, so that others can quickly spot the "right" answer to a question, in case they're ending up here by a web search. Ofc only do so, if it actually helped you answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an easiest way to create your textboxes as a table, you can Load the controls at runtime. You have to add only the first TextBox control to your form, set the name to "txtNo", and Index to 0 in the Properties window.

In your code, call Load() to create additional controls, and you can set the Top/Left and other properties

```
For i = 1 To 100
  Load txtNo(i)
  txtNo(i).Top = txtNo(i - 1).Top + txtNo(i - 1).Height + 150
  txtNo(i).Left = txtNo(i - 1).Left
  txtNo(i).Text = "Textbox " & i
  txtNo(i).Visible = True
Next i
```

If you need again to change any control property, from your list of controls, you can iterate only over your control list, instead of all controls of your Form

```
For i = txtNo.LBound() To txtNo.UBound()
  Form1.Controls("txtNo")(i).Text = "New text " & i
Next i
```